# CSS: Tooltip shown with distanse from parent on list scroll

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table inside `li` tag, and I want to show description on `:hover` inside `td`. For some reason when scrolling the list, the description content start to appear with distance from its parent.

I have tried many combinations of position setting of description content parent and itself, following tips I found here on site, but nothing works. I need to simply show description on hover when it appears on top of each element. With current CSS, if I scroll more, descriptions are shown more far from parent, as you can see in picture.

Before scroll:
[description, when list was not scrolled yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQKyh.png)

The bug: After some scroll: [description with distance, which relative to scroll amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWWrv.png)

```css
    .side div {
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 1%;
      padding-top: 1%;
      padding-right: 0.5%;
      width: 20%;
      background-color: #D9D9D9;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      box-shadow: 10px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      border-radius: 8px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .side table {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 8px;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }

    .side div table {
      border-radius: 8px;
      font-family: monospace;
      z-index: 995;
    }

    .side div table td {
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 7%;
      padding-top: 7%;
      padding-bottom: 7%;
    }

    .side div table td:first-child {
      padding-left: 1%;
      padding-right: 2%;
      font-size: auto;
      width: 30%;
    }

    .side div table tr:hover td:first-child {
      border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    }

    .side div table tr:hover td:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    }

    .side tr {
      display: table-row;
      color: #000000;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }

    .side tr td span {
      padding: 0px;
      text-decoration: none
    }

    .side table tr.active {
      background-color: #337AB7;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: white;
    }

    .side div table tr.active td:first-child {
      border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
    }

    .side div table tr.active td:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
    }

    .side table tr:hover:not(.active) {
      background-color: #B3B3B3;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: white;
    }

    .side {
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .side div ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      max-height: 33.333%;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }

    .side div ul:hover {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .description {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }
    .description-content {
      display: none;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding: 1%;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    .description:hover .description-content {
      max-height: 300px;
      max-width: 300px;
      min-width: 260px;
      min-height: 260px;
      display: block;
      background-color: #FCF8E3;
      color: #2E3436;
      z-index: 1001;
    }
    .description .description-content:hover {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="side">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <table class="subscribed-channels" 
                 data-ng-model="subscribedChannels">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="channel in subscribedChannels"
                data-ng-click="enterChannel(channel.ChannelName)" 
                data-ng-class="{active: isActive(channel.ChannelName)}">
              <td>channel</td>

              <td class="side-badges">...
              </td>
              <td>
                <data-button class="channel-control description">
                  <img class="channel-control-icon" 
                  data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info"/>
                  <div class="description-content">Description</div>
                </data-button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              
              <td>channel</td>

              <td class="side-badges">...
              </td>
              <td>
                <data-button class="channel-control description">
                  <img class="channel-control-icon" 
                  data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info"/>
                  <div class="description-content">Description</div>
                </data-button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              
              <td>channel</td>

              <td class="side-badges">...
              </td>
              <td>
                <data-button class="channel-control description">
                  <img class="channel-control-icon" 
                  data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info"/>
                  <div class="description-content">Description</div>
                </data-button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              
              <td>channel</td>

              <td class="side-badges">...
              </td>
              <td>
                <data-button class="channel-control description">
                  <img class="channel-control-icon" 
                  data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info"/>
                  <div class="description-content">Description</div>
                </data-button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              
              <td>channel</td>

              <td class="side-badges">...
              </td>
              <td>
                <data-button class="channel-control description">
                  <img class="channel-control-icon" 
                  data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info"/>
                  <div class="description-content">Description</div>
                </data-button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>channel</td>

              <td class="side-badges">...
              </td>
              <td>
                <data-button class="channel-control description">
                  <img class="channel-control-icon"
                  data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info"/>
                  <div class="description-content">Description</div>
                </data-button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Converted your code to snippet, can you make it actually run so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: fixed, now snippet reproduces the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use absolute positioning for this but your entire issue is the strange overflow you have set for the list.

```css
.side div {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-right: 0.5%;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #D9D9D9;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.side table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.side div table {
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  z-index: 995;
}
.side div table td {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 7%;
  padding-top: 7%;
  padding-bottom: 7%;
}
.side div table td:first-child {
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  font-size: auto;
  width: 30%;
}
.side div table tr:hover td:first-child {
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}
.side div table tr:hover td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.side tr {
  display: table-row;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.side tr td span {
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none
}
.side table tr.active {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
}
.side div table tr.active td:first-child {
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
}
.side div table tr.active td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.side table tr:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
}
.side {
  overflow: auto;
}
.side div ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.description {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.description-content {
  display: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.description:hover .description-content {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 260px;
  min-height: 260px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FCF8E3;
  color: #2E3436;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.description .description-content:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="side">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <table class="subscribed-channels" data-ng-model="subscribedChannels">
          <tr data-ng-repeat="channel in subscribedChannels" data-ng-click="enterChannel(channel.ChannelName)" data-ng-class="{active: isActive(channel.ChannelName)}">
            <td>channel</td>

            <td class="side-badges">...
            </td>
            <td>
              <data-button class="channel-control description">
                <img class="channel-control-icon" data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info" />
                <div class="description-content">Description</div>
              </data-button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>channel</td>

            <td class="side-badges">...
            </td>
            <td>
              <data-button class="channel-control description">
                <img class="channel-control-icon" data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info" />
                <div class="description-content">Description</div>
              </data-button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>channel</td>

            <td class="side-badges">...
            </td>
            <td>
              <data-button class="channel-control description">
                <img class="channel-control-icon" data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info" />
                <div class="description-content">Description</div>
              </data-button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>channel</td>

            <td class="side-badges">...
            </td>
            <td>
              <data-button class="channel-control description">
                <img class="channel-control-icon" data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info" />
                <div class="description-content">Description</div>
              </data-button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>channel</td>

            <td class="side-badges">...
            </td>
            <td>
              <data-button class="channel-control description">
                <img class="channel-control-icon" data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info" />
                <div class="description-content">Description</div>
              </data-button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>channel</td>

            <td class="side-badges">...
            </td>
            <td>
              <data-button class="channel-control description">
                <img class="channel-control-icon" data-ng-src="css/img/glyphicons-info-sign.png" alt="info" />
                <div class="description-content">Description</div>
              </data-button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. What I want to do is to show three lists, each of them need to catch 33.33% of the side panel. When each of the lists overflow with content, I want to show scroll bar for overflowed one, but only on mouse hover. And additionally to show this tooltip on hover on top of all elements. There is no way to achieve this goal?

Comment: I did as you proposed, to use absolute position,  I only changed `top: relative` and `left:23%` for description-content, so user don't need to jump with eyes to other place of the screen, and now it actually looks better. The only problem now is what to do when tooltip meets the bottom edge of the screen and almost unseen.